# Multiple regression ,mean absoluate error is high

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate X1^2+X2^2=Y using multiple regression in Phyton. In the CSV file, I have 2 columns X1 and X2 those are random numbers between 1 and 60. I want to predict y values of the test data. But the error of my model is too high.

```
 df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Büşra/Desktop/bitirme1/square-test.csv",sep=';')
 x = df[['X1','X2']]
 y = df[['Y']
 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3,random_state=1)
 x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape
 model1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
 model1.fit(x_train, y_train)
 print('Intercept: \n', model1.intercept_)
 print('Coefficients: \n', model1.coef_)
 print("Accuracy: %f" % model1.score(x_train,y_train)) 
 y_pred = abs(model1.predict(x_test))    
 print('Mean Absolute  Error:',(mean_absolute_error(y_test.to_numpy(), y_pred)))  
 print('Mean Squared Error:', (metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test.to_numpy(), y_pred)) ) 
 print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test.to_numpy(), y_pred)))
```

Mean Absolute  Error: 297.7286734942946

Mean Squared Error: 129653.26345373654

Root Mean Squared Error: 360.0739694198076

Comment: what is the question here? This is a normal output since the input values are random

Comment: As I understand it you have a `.csv` file with two columns; values of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. These will be the features of your regression. You have calculated your own target values using the formula $y=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}$ so you want to train a regression to take unseen input values for $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ and return a prediction for $y$? If so then you're not going to be able to use a linear regression as $y=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}$ is not a linear relationship.

Comment: I search the same model on the internet and the result of errors was fewer than mine.

Comment: There is no way to help you without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which includes data.

Comment: I have three columns x1,x2,y .The excel file calculates the y value directly using the formula method. Here I am splitting my data as train and test .I want to predict the y test values.

Comment: Is it possible that your errors are greater than the model you found on the internet because your data is sampled from a different distribution?

Comment: Yes, it might be. So, there is no problem. Thanks a lot for all of your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

The predictive power of your model is exactly what I'd expect from a linear regression trained on random data as you describe.

Below I train an Ordinary Least Squares linear regression on 10,000 pairs of random `x1`'s and `x2`'s where `0 <= x <= 60`, and `y = x1**2 + x2**2`. I then test it on 100 random pairs.

```py
import numpy as np
import sklearn.linear_model

X_train = np.random.rand(20000).reshape(10000,2)*60
y_train = (X_train[:, 0]**2)+(X_train[:, 1]**2)
X_test = np.random.rand(200).reshape(100,2)*60
y_test = (X_test[:, 0]**2)+(X_test[:, 1]**2)

model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print("MAE: {}".format(np.abs(y_test-y_pred).mean()))
print("RMSE: {}".format(np.sqrt(((y_test-y_pred)**2).mean())))
```

It gives me exactly the same errors as it gives you.

```
>>> python .\regression.py
MAE: 301.35977152696194
RMSE: 363.663670758086
```

Here is a plot illustrating why the regression cannot obtain better results than this. The features (`x1` and `x1`) are on the x and y axes, and the target (`y`) is on the z-axis. The red dots are the training samples and the blue plane is the function that the regression produces.

A Linear Regression can only produce a function of the form `y = w1·x1 + w2·x2 + w3` where `w1`, `w2` and `w3` are the weights being optimised by the regression. This type of function generates a flat plane, like the one shown. In this case the equation fit is `y = -1249.41 + 61.18x1 + 60.69x2`. This is clearly not the same type of function that generated the samples, which follow a nice curved surface.

[image: 3D plot of regression]

The effect is much clearer if you [run the code yourself](https://gist.github.com/aricooperdavis/c658fc1c5d9bdc5b50ec94602328073b) so that you can move the 3D plot around and more easily see the shapes.

Comment: I tried to plot this `LinearRegression` by using `scatterplot` like [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-in-6-lines-of-python-5e1d0cd05b8d), but I couldn't due to you defined it pairs of random. Is it possible to visualize this regression?

Comment: Well this regression has two features so it's not as simple as plotting one feature against one target like in the link you sent. You could probably plot it as on Matplotlib's 3D axis. Give me a second and I'll write up a Gist to demonstrate that.

Comment: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/aricooperdavis/c658fc1c5d9bdc5b50ec94602328073b) illustrating a plot of this question. It has the features on the x and y axes and the target on the z axis. The plane illustrates the result of the linear regression - note that it is a plane rather than a more complex shape that would fit the data better. This is why the linear regression cannot perfectly match the data or obtain the function used to generate it.

Comment: Thanks for providing the visualization in the form of 3D plot. It seems the plane, which is our regression model is always higher than scatter points! It might be due to the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @Mario That confused me, because it shouldn't be! I forgot to subtract the intercept from the function; I've updated the plot with how it should look. The issue is because the flat plane can't curve to fit the data points because the function is linear so this is as close as it can get.

Comment: That's right, and now it looks much realistic ;) thanks for update the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you are looking for a model of the form `y = a*x_1 + b*x_2 + c` to approximate the function `y = x_1**2 + x_2**2` by linear regression. If your variables `x_1` and `x_2` are drawn uniformly at random from the range 0-60, the mean squared error over this range is exactly

[image: double integral]

This is minimized when a = 60, b = 60 and c = -1200, so this is the best theoretically possible linear model, and your model should converge to it as it is trained on more data. This model has an MSE of 144,000 and an RMSE of **379.473**. This about matches your model, so it looks like there is no problem with your results.

Your RMSE could be slightly lower than the "theoretically best RMSE" because it is measured over a sample rather than the whole uniform distribution. You should also get slightly different results for the range 1-60, or if your data only contains integers, or so on.